# Visual Studio Code reports errors in Parcel project with TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx, parceljs

I'm using Parcel 2.9.3 to build a webapp in TypeScript + React.

According to the docs https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/#jsx:

> Parcel supports JSX automatically when it detects you are using React.
> If you’re using React 17 or later, it also automatically enables the
> modern JSX transform, which means you don't even need to import React
> for JSX to work

`parcel serve src/index.html` and `parcel build src/index.html` works without errors.

But without adding the `tsconfig.json`, the Visual Studio Code reports errors in `tsx` files. For example, `App.tsx`

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

[image: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.]

When I add the following `tsconfig.json`, Visual Studio Code stops reporting this error:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

But with such `tsconfig.json` I get the new error when defining a web worker:

```js
new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url), {
  type: 'module',
});
```

```
The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.
```

Then `tsconfig.json` becomes

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler"
  }
}
```

Is creating such `tsconfig.json` the correct way of integrating Parcel with the Visual Studio Code for TypeScript + React project? What else should be added to the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Hi, have you found a proper solution? I'm also struggling with this currently and can't find any info except your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `tsconfig.json` to `src` directory solves Visual Studio Code error:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

It also lets doing type checking with command:

```
tsc --noEmit -p ./src/tsconfig.json
```